# WSL Error: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: docker, wsl-2

Issue Faced:

Even after installing WSL and after running below command, I was getting error: `The file cannot be accessed by the system.`

1. `wsl --set-default-version 2`
2. Error : The file cannot be accessed by the system

Refer Below Screen Shot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, presumably after an automatic update.

I tried various things like running `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and "repairing" the Windows Subsystem for Linux in `Add/Remove Programs` without success.

I also tried to update the kernel via `wsl --update --web-download` and encountered a `Catastrophic Failure`.

After reading https://superuser.com/questions/1731365/updating-wsl-2-without-microsoft-store I solved the problem as follows.

**Solution:**

1. Open `Event Viewer` & find log `Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational`
2. My log stated the following:

> AppX Deployment operation failed for package
> MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_2.0.14.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> with error 0x80073D19. The specific error text for this failure is:
> Deployment of package
> MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_2.0.14.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
> was blocked because the provided package has the same identity as an
> already-installed package but the contents are different. Increment
> the version number of the package to be installed, or remove the old
> package for every user on the system before installing this package.

3. I reinstalled the installed version of wsl via cmdline with the command `misexec /package wsl.2.0.14.0.x64`
4. `wsl` worked as usual

You can download the wsl packages from the wsl github release page https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

To resolve this issue run the below command.

1. `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
2. Restart the system.

**OR**

Do followings.

1. Windows logo key -> type linux -> 'Windows Subsystem for Linuxappears -> you can seeApp Settings` in the right pane, hit that menu.
2. When Settings windows open, you can see the Reset button. after the reset, It works like a charm!

References: [Link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9197)